# Separate bar plot into multiple plots based on the first column value

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I do have a data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sample_ids':['sample1a_1', 'sample1b_2', 'sample1c_3', 'sample2a_2', 'sample2b_4'], 
                   'perc_A':[0.75,0.66667,0.70213,0.83333,0.5],
                   'perc_B':[0.18182,0.24747,0.28176,0.16529,0.26316],
                   'perc_C':[0.4222,0.15823,0.17925,0.55556,0.21053]})
```

I would like to plot multiple 100% stacked and grouped bar charts based on the sample_ids. For example, sample1a_1, sample1b_2, sample1c_3 will be in one plot, while sample2a_2 and sample2b_4 will be in another plot. Another way of explanation, if the first six characters are the same, then the bar should be within the same figure.

Example of expected figures: 
Figure N1:
[image]

Figure N2:
[image]

---

Current code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,10)

df = pd.DataFrame({'sample_ids':['sample1a_1', 'sample1b_2', 'sample1a_3', 'sample2a_2', 'sample2b_4'], 
                   'perc_A':[0.75,0.66667,0.70213,0.83333,0.5],
                   'perc_B':[0.18182,0.24747,0.28176,0.16529,0.26316],
                   'perc_C':[0.4222,0.15823,0.17925,0.55556,0.21053]})

df[['perc_F_A', 'perc_F_B', 'perc_F_C']] = 1

meltedDF = df.melt(id_vars=['sample_ids'], var_name='perc', value_name='percent')
meltedDF['percent']=meltedDF['percent']*100

sns.barplot(data=meltedDF[meltedDF.perc.str.contains('F')], x='sample_ids', y='percent', hue='perc', palette=['blue','green','red'], alpha=0.5)
sns.barplot(data=meltedDF[~meltedDF.perc.str.contains('F')], x='sample_ids', y='percent', hue='perc', palette=['blue','green','red'])

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0)
plt.xlabel("Sample ID")
plt.ylabel("Percentage (%)")

plt.show()
```

and current figure:
[image]

Comment: you may have to create `subplots()` and get two axis and later use `sns.barplot( ..., ax= ...)` to plot on different subplot (different axis `ax`). But first it will need to split data into 2 sets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have manually create two subplots and get two axis

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)
```

And later you has to split data

```
v1 = meltedDF[ meltedDF['sample_ids'].isin(['sample1a_1', 'sample1b_2', 'sample1a_3']) ]
v2 = meltedDF[ meltedDF['sample_ids'].isin(['sample2a_2', 'sample2b_4']) ]
```

and draw them on different axis `sns.barplot(..., ax=...)`

---

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,10)

df = pd.DataFrame({'sample_ids':['sample1a_1', 'sample1b_2', 'sample1a_3', 'sample2a_2', 'sample2b_4'], 
                   'perc_A':[0.75,0.66667,0.70213,0.83333,0.5],
                   'perc_B':[0.18182,0.24747,0.28176,0.16529,0.26316],
                   'perc_C':[0.4222,0.15823,0.17925,0.55556,0.21053]})

df[['perc_F_A', 'perc_F_B', 'perc_F_C']] = 1

meltedDF = df.melt(id_vars=['sample_ids'], var_name='perc', value_name='percent')
meltedDF['percent'] = meltedDF['percent']*100

# --------------

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)

# --- plot 1 ---

v1 = meltedDF[ meltedDF['sample_ids'].isin(['sample1a_1', 'sample1b_2', 'sample1a_3']) ]

sns.barplot(ax=ax1, data=v1[v1.perc.str.contains('F')],  x='sample_ids', y='percent', hue='perc', palette=['blue','green','red'], alpha=0.5)
sns.barplot(ax=ax1, data=v1[~v1.perc.str.contains('F')], x='sample_ids', y='percent', hue='perc', palette=['blue','green','red'])

ax1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0)
ax1.set_xlabel("Sample ID")      # plt.xlabel("Sample ID")
ax1.set_ylabel("Percentage (%)") # plt.ylabel("Percentage (%)")

# --- plot 2 ---

v2 = meltedDF[ meltedDF['sample_ids'].isin(['sample2a_2', 'sample2b_4']) ]

sns.barplot(ax=ax2, data=v2[v2.perc.str.contains('F')],  x='sample_ids', y='percent', hue='perc', palette=['blue','green','red'], alpha=0.5)
sns.barplot(ax=ax2, data=v2[~v2.perc.str.contains('F')], x='sample_ids', y='percent', hue='perc', palette=['blue','green','red'])

ax2.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0)
ax2.set_xlabel("Sample ID")      # plt.xlabel("Sample ID")
ax2.set_ylabel("Percentage (%)") # plt.ylabel("Percentage (%)")

# --------------

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

And if you want to automate it then you can use `for`-loop and `dict` to split it

```
splitted = {}

for item in df['sample_ids']:
    prefix = item[:7]
    if prefix not in splitted:
        splitted[prefix] = []
    splitted[prefix].append(item)
    
for key, val in splitted.items():
    print(key, val)
```

Result:

```
sample1 ['sample1a_1', 'sample1b_2', 'sample1a_3']
sample2 ['sample2a_2', 'sample2b_4']
```

And later you can use `for`-loop to plot all subdata

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,10)

df = pd.DataFrame({'sample_ids':['sample1a_1', 'sample1b_2', 'sample1a_3', 'sample2a_2', 'sample2b_4'], 
                   'perc_A':[0.75,0.66667,0.70213,0.83333,0.5],
                   'perc_B':[0.18182,0.24747,0.28176,0.16529,0.26316],
                   'perc_C':[0.4222,0.15823,0.17925,0.55556,0.21053]})

df[['perc_F_A', 'perc_F_B', 'perc_F_C']] = 1

meltedDF = df.melt(id_vars=['sample_ids'], var_name='perc', value_name='percent')
meltedDF['percent'] = meltedDF['percent']*100

# --------------

splitted = {}

for item in df['sample_ids']:
    prefix = item[:7]
    if prefix not in splitted:
        splitted[prefix] = []
    splitted[prefix].append(item)
    
for key, val in splitted.items():
    print(key, val)

# --------------

fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(splitted))

for ax, (key, val) in zip(axs, splitted.items()):
    
    subdata = meltedDF[ meltedDF['sample_ids'].isin(val) ]

    sns.barplot(ax=ax, data=subdata[subdata.perc.str.contains('F')],  x='sample_ids', y='percent', hue='perc', palette=['blue','green','red'], alpha=0.5)
    sns.barplot(ax=ax, data=subdata[~subdata.perc.str.contains('F')], x='sample_ids', y='percent', hue='perc', palette=['blue','green','red'])

    ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0)
    ax.set_xlabel("Sample ID")      # plt.xlabel("Sample ID")
    ax.set_ylabel("Percentage (%)") # plt.ylabel("Percentage (%)")

# --------------

plt.show()
```

---

**EDIT:**

You may also try to split it using `groupby()`

```
for key, val in df.groupby(df['sample_ids'].str[:7]):
    print('---', key, '---')
    #print(val['sample_ids'])
    print(val)
```

Result:

```
--- sample1 ---
   sample_ids   perc_A   perc_B   perc_C  perc_F_A  perc_F_B  perc_F_C
0  sample1a_1  0.75000  0.18182  0.42220         1         1         1
1  sample1b_2  0.66667  0.24747  0.15823         1         1         1
2  sample1a_3  0.70213  0.28176  0.17925         1         1         1
--- sample2 ---
   sample_ids   perc_A   perc_B   perc_C  perc_F_A  perc_F_B  perc_F_C
3  sample2a_2  0.83333  0.16529  0.55556         1         1         1
4  sample2b_4  0.50000  0.26316  0.21053         1         1         1
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Is there any automated way as I have more than 60 samples?

Comment: see second version with use dictionary `splitted = {}` and `for`-loop to split `sample_ids`. And later it use `for`-loop to generate many plots

Comment: Thank you. I am able to get it now.